# How to serializeObject with nested object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
 "resource_ratio": [
            [
               "Barbara",
               "Ben",
               "Anne",
               "John",
               "Cindy",
               "Nick",
               "Lex",
               "Edd",
               "Eric",
               "Jacky",
               "Paul"
            ],
            [
               0.11974110032362459,
               0.037756202804746494,
               0.23516720604099245,
               0.10895361380798274,
               0.10140237324703344,
               0.03559870550161812,
               0.02912621359223301,
               0.08737864077669903,
               0.02481121898597627,
               0.1186623516720604,
               0.10140237324703344
            ]
         ]
```

this 2 dim array that I want to display on HTML page using javascript
and then get the result back in JSON from after clicking a button.

For now, I displayed the values of resource_raio using this

```
var resourceRatioBoxTag = new Array();
  var resourceRatioTag = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedData.resource_ratio.length; i++) {
    //selectedData.resource_ratio[1][0]
    resourceRatioBoxTag[i] = "<input id='resourceRatio[" + i + "]' name='resourceRatio'>";
    for (var j = 0; j < selectedData.resource_ratio[i].length; j++) {
      resourceRatioBoxTag[i] += "<input type='text' id='resourceRatio[" + i + "][" + j + "]' value='" + selectedData.resource_ratio[i][j] + "' name='" + i + "'>";
    }
    resourceRatioBoxTag[i] += "</input>";
     $("#resourceRatioDiv").append(resourceRatioBoxTag[i]);
  }
```

which gave me result of one single array with all the values inside like [val1, val2, val3]

And when I do

```
var dataBox = $('#inputDataForm').serializeObject();
```

the JSON result

It's not in form of

> "resource_ratio": [
> [
> "Barbara",
> "Ben",
> "Anne",
> "John",
> "Cindy",
> "Nick",
> "Lex",
> "Edd",
> "Eric",
> "Jacky",
> "Paul"
> ],
> [
> 0.11974110032362459,
> 0.037756202804746494,
> 0.23516720604099245,
> 0.10895361380798274,
> 0.10140237324703344,
> 0.03559870550161812,
> 0.02912621359223301,
> 0.08737864077669903,
> 0.02481121898597627,
> 0.1186623516720604,
> 0.10140237324703344
> ]
> ]

as I wanted it to be. So I've tried changing the name of the input of array values (Since I've learned that SerializeObject group values by the name of input) and made something like this

```
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedData.resource_ratio.length; i++) {
    //selectedData.resource_ratio[1][0]
    resourceRatioBoxTag[i] = "<p id='resourceRatio[" + i + "]' name='resourceRatio'>";
    for (var j = 0; j < selectedData.resource_ratio[i].length; j++) {
      resourceRatioBoxTag[i] += "<input type='text' id='resourceRatio[" + i + "][" + j + "]' value='" + selectedData.resource_ratio[i][j] + "' name='" + i + "'>";
    }
    resourceRatioBoxTag[i] += "</p>";
     $("#resourceRatioDiv").append(resourceRatioBoxTag[i]);
  }
```

(Its the same code except I changed the p tag to input tag]

which gave me serialized values of

```
"0": [
    "Barbara",
    "Ben",
    "Anne",
    "John",
    "Cindy",
    "Nick",
    "Lex",
    "Edd",
    "Eric",
    "Jacky",
    "Paul"
  ],
  "1": [
    "0.11974110032362459",
    "0.037756202804746494",
    "0.23516720604099245",
    "0.10895361380798274",
    "0.10140237324703344",
    "0.03559870550161812",
    "0.02912621359223301",
    "0.08737864077669903",
    "0.02481121898597627",
    "0.1186623516720604",
    "0.10140237324703344"
  ]
```

which is ALMOST same as how I want it to be, except it's not INSIDE the resource_ratio values, it's grouped by [0] and [1] (following by the input name).

What should I do to get my resourceRatio[i][j] values inside [i] which is inside the resourceRatio key? I'm sorry if my question is so confusing

the serializeObject is a plug in of jquery I used. It's this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
  var o = {};
  var a = this.serializeArray();
  $.each(a, function () {
    if (o[this.name]) {
      if (!o[this.name].push) {
        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
      }
      o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
      o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
  });
  return o;
};
```

Comment: Please don't use images to reflect your data structure or your code. Please replace your images with the actual artifact. Thanks.

Comment: @RandyCasburn hello I've tried removing the pictures is this working fine?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't realize jQuery had a `.serializeObject()` method. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Oh my bad.. this is a plugin of jquery i used. I'm sorry. Should I change the tag too??

Comment: Yeah, so it doesn't look like you need the plugin. You will get the same result using `.serializeArray()`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The result is different between serializeObject() and serializeArray(). when I use serializeArray() it gives me result in [{name : val1, value: val1}, . . .] but when I use seralizeObject it gives me the result in form I want (JSON from) which is like "key1" : ["val1", "val2"]

Comment: EDIT: Yeah, so it doesn't look like you need the plugin. You will get a better result using `.serializeArray()`. The reason you are getting ` 0 : [...]` is because you are using `.serializeObject()` which is creating an object instead of an array.

Comment: No, it isn't really the. format you've described above. You want the serialized form elements in a nested array (what you call a 2 dim array). But, you want that 2 dimensional array to be the value associated with a key named `resource_ratio`. So your final result should look like this: `{resource_ratio: [ [ ... ], [...] ]}`, not this: `{resource_ratio: { 0: [...], 1: [...] }}` - these are a nested objects, not a 2 dim array.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you, the last comment helped me understanding the problem but when I use var testBox = $('#inputDataForm').serializeArray(); it gives me result of [{"name":"resourceRatio","value":"Nick"},{"name":"resourceRatio","value":"Lex"} ...] instead of the {resource_ratio: { 0: [...], 1: [...] }} form. I'm confused :(

Comment: I see, yes, go back to using `.serializeObject()`. Create a new variable: `data = {}`, then just after your call to `.serializeObject()`, do this: `data["resource_ratio", Object.values(dataBox);` - your new `data` object should be in the correct format.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Hi, I get result of undefined with var dataBox = $('#inputDataForm').serializeObject();
      var data = {};
      console.log(data["resource_ratio", Object.values(dataBox)]);
      console.log(data["resource_ratio", Object.values(dataBox.resourceRatio)]);

Comment: @RandyCasburn Ohhh I think I kinda know how to fix this I'll try. Thank you for your help it helped me a lot !! I'm going to use data["resource_ratio", Object.values(dataBox); <- this to work so that I can get the result I want

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a value to JSON is to use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
let dataAsString = JSON.stringify( myObject )
```

This will break if your object has any circular references. That won't be a problem if your data is a typical piece of business data.

And then to convert it back:

```js
let data = JSON.parse( dataAsString )
```

Unless you have a very special reason for doing so, I'd recommend that you always use this built-in capability instead of something from a library like jQuery.